# SelectSingleNode as lower case

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Ive been looking at SO and found many Q&A that could be the same type of problem, but I cant get mine to work, im doing something wrong.

When I extract a certain `<meta` tags I do it in this manner

```
HtmlNode clnode = 
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@http-equiv='content-type']");
```

This work just fine, except it wont match

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Ive tried to use the lower-case() function like this,

```
HtmlNode ctnode = 
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[lower-case(@http-equiv)='content-type']");
```

but it does not work.

I am using the latest `HtmlAgilityPack`.

How can i solve this? **Is there maybe a better way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use xpath selection, as far as I'm aware `HtmlAgilityPack` uses XPath 1.0, so you need to resort to some ugly hacks, e.g.:

```
HtmlNode clnode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[translate(@http-equiv,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='content-type']");
```

Alternatively you can simply use LINQ:

```
var clnode= htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                   .Elements("meta")
                   .SingleOrDefault(el => el.Attributes["http-equiv"].Value.ToLower() == "content-type");
```

Comment: Thanks @decPL. Beautiful LINQ solution, i will use that one! Thanks again!